# How to save file from ADODB.Stream to table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query what save data from `Image` column to disc:

```
declare @x varbinary(max)
declare @xz varbinary(max)
declare  @OLEStream Int, @ErrCode   Int
declare @FileName nvarchar(4000) = N'd:\temp1.pdf'

set @x =(SELECT [_Fld3351] FROM [mydb].[dbo].[_InfoRg3349] WHERE<> )



exec @ErrCode = sys.sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream' ,@OLEStream OUT

exec @ErrCode = sys.sp_OASetProperty @OLEStream , 'CharSet' ,'utf-8'
exec @ErrCode = sys.sp_OASetProperty @OLEStream ,'Type' , 1
exec @ErrCode = sys.sp_OAMethod @OLEStream ,'Open'
exec @ErrCode = sys.sp_OAMethod @OLEStream ,'Write', null, @x


EXEC @ErrCode = sp_OAMethod @OLEStream,'SaveToFile',null, @FileName,2 
EXEC @ErrCode = sp_OAMethod @OLEStream,'Close'
```

Now i want to write this data in `varbinary(max)` column.
Never work with `sp_OAMethod` commands before, so how can i modify code to write data to table?

Comment: Why use `sp_OAMethod` to copy/move data from an `image` column (`image` has been deprecated for 15 years by the way) to a `varbinary`? What's wrong with an `INSERT`/`UPDATE`?

Comment: If your data is already in a table and you want to write it to another table you don't need to involve ADODB and invoking ancient COM objects

Comment: @Larnu This is kind of triky data. When i tried to just convert(varbinary(max),[_Fld3351]) and put it to my table i got a non valid files. Even when i try to save `Image` column data to disc using `bcp` files stil non-valid. So i found that using  `sp_OAMethod` is only way to get valid files.

Comment: Then you need to troubleshoot that.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft So i just can not to save data to table?

Comment: Writing the data to a file and reading it back again using deprecated COM components is not a reasonable solution, nor is it terribly simple to do.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I know that this is a bad solution. But i don't know why files is non-valid. All i know that 'Image' column contains some(10) bytes in begining what i can not remove with `substring`. But when i use `sp_OAMethod` all works.

Comment: Look at the contents of the column and figure out whether it's valid, and if not how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As part of your troubleshooting, here's how to load that file into a varbinary(max) column so you can compare it with the source column and figure out what's going on.

```
insert into SomeTable(BlobColumn)
select BulkColumn 
from openrowset(bulk  N'c:\temp\test.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) b
```